# Reference books or any sources advice for my advanced calculus course

Tags: reference-request, multivariable-calculus, integration

My course outline:

Differentiation of functions of several variables: partial derivatives, differential, differentiability, inverse function theorem, implicit function theorem, free extremum problems, constrained extremum problem, method of Lagrange multipliers

Integration in $R^n$:measure zero and content zero sets, integrability, Fubini's Theorem, partition of unity, change of variables

Integration on chains: tensors, alternating tensors, vector fields, differential forms, Poincare Lemma, Stokes' Theorem

Comment: The classical source for most of these topics is Rudin : Principles of Mathematical Analysis.

Comment: ([tag:reference-request]) should not be used as a standalone tag; see [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info) and [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags).

Answer (score 1):

The book by Moskowitz and Paliogiannis: Functions of Several Real Variables, discusses almost all the above topics in detail, and I strongly recommend it. It is rigorous with many good Examples and Problems with Hints and full Solutions.